# Find unitary matrix given its image.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

I'm trying to solve this:

Let $$D_{0}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4\\ 
2 & 5\\ 
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$$

Find a D such that $$D^{*}D=I$$$$\operatorname{Im}D_{0}=\operatorname{Im}D$$
(D* is complex conjugate transpose of D)

I tried as following:

1. Calculate $$\operatorname{Im}D_{0}=\begin{Bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 
    0 \\ 
    -1 
   \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
   0\\ 
   1\\ 
   2
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{Bmatrix}$$
2. Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   0\\ 
   -1
   \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   0\\ 
   -1
   \end{bmatrix},\qquad\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\ 
   1\\ 
   2
   \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   1\\ 
   1
   \end{bmatrix}$$
3. Let $$ v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   0\\ 
   -1
   \end{bmatrix},\quad v_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   1\\ 
   1
   \end{bmatrix},\quad v_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
   a\\ 
   b\\ 
   c
   \end{bmatrix}$$
   We have $$D=\begin{bmatrix}
   v_{1} &v_{2}  &v_{3} \\ 
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Because D*D=I, D is an unitary matrix. So $$\langle v_{1},v_{3}\rangle =0$$ and $$\langle v_{1},v_{3}\rangle =0$$

Solve above inner product equation. I have:
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} &1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{6}\\
0&1/\sqrt{3}&-2/\sqrt{6}\\
-1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{3}&1/\sqrt{6}\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Check my result: $D^*D = I$ -> correct

But the problem is: 
$$\operatorname{Im}D=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\neq \operatorname{Im}D_{0}???$$
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\ D^*D=I\ $ only implies that $\ D\ $ is unitary if it is *square*. As stated in your question *without* the requirement imposed by the statement in your heading that it be *unitary*, the problem can be solved if (and only  if) you take the matrix $\ D\ $ to be $\ 3\times2\ $.  In fact, you've already taken most of the steps to solve it.  The columns of $\ D\ $ just need to be an orthonormal basis for the column space of $\ D_0\ $, and if you take those columns to be the first two columns of your attempted construction, that condition will be satisfied.  That is, take
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
0&  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ 
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
You will then have $\ D^*D=I_{2\times2}\ $ and $\ \operatorname{Im}\left(D_0\right)= \operatorname{Im}(D)\ $.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The equation ${D^{*}D=I}$ does not imply unitary matrix.
Thank you

Comment: One thing I don't understand is that why D must be 3x2 matrix? Why not 3x3, 3x4 or 3x5?

Comment: If $\ D^*D=I_{n\times n}\ $, then $\ D\ $ must have $\ n\ $ columns, and they must be linearly independent (otherwise there would be an $\ n\times 1\ $ non-zero column vector vector $\ x\ $ such that $\ 0_{n\times1}=$$D^*Dx=$$I_{n\times n}x\ $, which is obviously impossible). That is, the dimension of the column space of  $\ D\ $ must be $\ n\ $. But if $\ \operatorname{Im}(D)=\operatorname{Im}\left(D_0\right)$, then the column space of $\ D\ $ must have the same dimension as the column space of $\ D_0\ $, namely $2$. So $\ n\ $ must be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a $3 \times 3$ unitary matrix (which is known to be invertible) with a 2D (dimension 2) image space, because that would mean that the kernel is 1D (by rank-nullity theorem) ; alas, a matrix with a 1D kernel is not invertible. Contradiction...

You must look for a matrix $D$ which is $3 \times 2$ (3 lines and 2 columns).

Comment: Yes, you are right. a 3×3 matrix with 2D image space will have determinant = 0, which means not invertible.
Thank you.